# the result from finding key using value from a python dictionary didnt go as planned

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
c = {0: [0, 2, 3], 1: [1, 6, 9]}
```

and I have this list:

```
f = [1, 0, 6]
```

and I want to know for every member in f, what is the key in the dictionary c?

Here is the code I am using to achieve this:

```
for m, n in c.items():
    for k in n:
        for l in f:         
            if k == l:
                print(m)
```

and I get this result:

```
0
1
1
```

but I think the result should be:

```
1
0
1
```

What can I do to make the result like what I want it to be?

I really appreciate you help.

Thank you.

Comment: can you explain how you reached that conclusion? what do you think you're printing? keys, values, indexes? and fix your indentation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping over the items of `C`; iteration over a dictionary takes place in a *implementation specific, internal order* (see [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)). Since you did not also print the `k` variable, you have no idea what was paired with what.

You'd have to loop over `n` in the outer loop if you wanted to print things in the same order:

```
for k in f:
    for m, n in C.items():
        if k in n:
            print m
            break
```

I adjusted the inner loop to use a list membership test with `in`, and I used `break` to stop further searching.

Using dictionaries like this is rather counter-productive. If `n` is large, consider creating an inverse index instead:

```
inverse = {}
for m, n in C.items():
    for i in n:
        inverse.setdefault(i, set()).add(m)
```

then use that to do fast lookups:

```
for k in f:
    print inverse.get(k, set())
```

The inverse holds *sets* of keys for a given value (since there could easily be more than one list in which a value appears).

Comment: ♦ thanks man. i just run my code in one of those visualize python shell to know how my code run and i just realize my loop is totally wrong. thanks for teaching me something today.